# Springboot build

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a system built over Springboot framework which runs two services, as shown:

[image]

I need to build stock-quote-manager in order to containerize it.
I've tried to build it using mvnw this way:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:build-image
```

But It throws an error which leads me to belive i'll need to refactor the whole code, moving stockquotemanager or stockmanager to another package. Is there any other way to build it whithout any refactor?

Here is the mvnw error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  33.107 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-28T10:33:14-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) on project stock-quote-manager: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.br.inatel.stockmanager.StockManagerApplication, com.br.inatel.stockquotemanager.StockQuoteManagerApplication] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I don't know if it's relevant but StockManager runs on port 8080 and stockQuoteManager on port 8081.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are having multiple main methods for one project, StockQuoteManagerApplication, and StockManagerApplication. you have to separate these two and run them in separate tomcat instances(i.e. create two different projects) then only you'll get two separate ports for each service. Because they both are running in the same tomcat instance only one port will be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Docker` file inside the Project folder and do the following as stated inside the official Spring documentation.

[Spring Boot with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)
Thank you.